# query to find difference between two time data record

Tags: time

I have a table that contains the following datetime and customer

example :

data1 :
datetime : 2011-7-25 10:23:30 AM

customer:A

data2 :
datetime : 2011-7-25 10:40:30 AM

customer:B

I need query to know time duration between Customer A and B,

I am using Firebird database. thank you before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about [`DATEDIFF`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-intfunc-datediff.html)?

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(second, -- or the unit you want
           a.datetime, b.datetime) AS result
FROM ExampleTable a, ExampleTable b
WHERE a.customer = 'A' and b.customer = 'B'
```

Comment: thank you mark for your quick response, but i need not only customer A and B. I mean i have a thousand customer every day and i need to know duration between one customer to another customer it's that possible ? i already using join table but it seems firebird doesn't support it

Comment: The duration between *every* customer? Or between which customers?

Comment: duration between every customer :)... thank you so much  marc , i really appreciate it, but  i already found the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427672/sqlite-time-difference-between-query-result-rows-how-to