# SQlite Time Difference using function strftime and date and using trigger to update on insert 

Tags: sqlite, function, time, strftime

I want to have the difference between two timestamps, like

```
Endtime = strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S','now','localtime') 
firsttime = strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S','2012-01-27 02:34:56')
```

i.e. if my firsttime is 2012-06-15 14:54:33 and Endtime is 2012-06-15 14:54:40 
then time diff would be like this =00:00:14;

I want to have such difference between timestamps, like `Endtime-firsttime`

I also want to use trigger to do use in SQLite database in Android.

In SQL we can do it by means of converting using the `time to second` function and `second to time` functions.

Any suggestion would be appreciated, however I can get time differences in Java easily but my application has lots of other work. So I wish I could achieve the same using a SQLite  built-in function so the burden on the application becomes less.

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427672/time-difference-between-query-result-rows-how-to

Comment: thanks i tried but it was giving only second in difference , I tried as SELECT strftime('%M','now','localtime')-strftime('%M','2012-06-27 13:50:00','localtime') but it does not too

Comment: Try this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289680/difference-between-2-dates-in-sqlite

Comment: thanks it does not work the way i m looking                               select datetime((julianday(datetime('now')))-julianday(datetime('2012-06-28 13:18:00')))