# solution for SQLite function for time difference without java code

Tags: android, function, sqlite

Hey please pay attention to solve this problem I know this could be possible but I am not getting the way .. 
I am using sqlite in android to store and manipulate the field as shown below in the figure

[Figure http://s16.postimage.org/idc13pxdh/image.png](http://s16.postimage.org/idc13pxdh/image.png)

first_start_time,last_start_time,last_end_time are datetime field in SQLite database

I need to get the difference of last_start_time and last_end_time as mean of function so that I don't need to do it programatically

```
last_end_time = strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S','now','localtime') 
last_start_time= strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S','2012-01-27 02:34:56')
```

,i,e if my firsttime is =2012-06-15 14:54:33

and Endtime is =2012-06-15 14:54:40

then time diff would be like this =00:00:14;

i want to have such difference time like last_end_time -last_start_time

i also want to use trigger to do use in sqlite data base in android

at the last I need that all my total_expended_time should get summed up like ...

```
select sum(total_expended_time) from study_result
```

.. one thing keep in mind the result should be in datetime stamp so that i can reflect it to my UI

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQlite Time Difference using function strftime and date and using trigger to update on insert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221509/sqlite-time-difference-using-function-strftime-and-date-and-using-trigger-to-upd)